# Setting a column's default value to be the logged in user name in Access 2007

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

I have an Access file developed using Access 2003, and am trying to work with it using Access 2007.

Some tables have a "changedby" column, which has a default value of

```
=Environ("username")
```

This is triggering an error

*Unknown function 'Environ' in validation expression or default value on market.changedby*

Is there a replacement function available in Access 2007, which can be used as a formula in a default value for a column?

Comment: I think you are mixing your layers: putting calls to DLLs in the ACE/Jet layer that can only be called by Access; mixing audit data with application data. Can't you use User Level Security for this? Oh ywah: they removed that from the engine :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this [thread](http://www.access-programmers.co.uk/forums/showthread.php?t=115442).

It's states that you have to wrap the environ call in a [function](http://www.access-programmers.co.uk/forums/showthread.php?t=76173) to get around the Access "sandbox"

Another poster says you can set the macor security to low to fix it as well.

Comment: And UDFs cannot be used as default values in Jet tables. I doubt that ACE changes that, but can't check it myself.